# ¿Cómo inicializar correctamente un candado (mutex)?

Tags: c, hilos, proceso

Soy nuevo en la programación concurrente y estoy practicando con procesos e hilos, por el momento estoy implementando tareas de tipo hilo con las herramientas de POSIX:

```
pthread_t
pthread_create();
pthread_init();
pthread_mutex_t
```

Hasta el momento solo tengo una duda: ¿cómo inicializo POR DEFAULT un candado (mutex) como bloqueado, SIN USAR LA INSTRUCCIÓN `pthread_mutex_lock();` algo como este pseudocódigo:

variables compartidas:

```
int x;
```

candados:

```
C1=1 //cerrado

tareaA(){
     x=rand()%5;
     unlock(C1);
}

tareaB(){
   lock(C1);
   imprime(x);
}
```

cómo inicializar ése candado C1 como bloqueado, en el lenguaje C.

Answer (score 1):

Los candados sirven para proteger regiones críticas del código las cuales no admiten concurrencia so pena de crear inconsistencias u otros problemas. El uso esperado de un candado es bloquearlo al entrar en la región crítica y desbloquearlo al salir de la misma. Un uso como el que planteas únicamente va a crear confusión y puede ser toda una fuente de problemas dentro de tu aplicación.

Conseguir lo que pretendes es más sencillo. Puedes usar una variable booleana adicional a modo de flag para indicar que hay datos a imprimir. `tareaA` pondrá esa variable a `true` cuando almacene un valor en la variable y `tareaB` comprobará de forma recurrente ese valor para saber cuándo debe imprimir el valor:

```
bool hayDato = false;

tareaA(){
  lock(C1);
  x=rand()%5;
  hayDato = true;
  unlock(C1);
}

tareaB(){
  lock(C1);
  if( hayDato == true ){
    hayDato = false;
    imprime(x);
  }
  unlock(C1);
}
```

PD.: `bool` es un alias definido en la cabecera `stdbool.h`.

Un saludo.

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta me sirvió de mucho y perdona por la tardía respuesta.